# How to filter out values from pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. I need to filter some values from the main dataframe. I need some help to do this. Could you please help me?

Explain:

df_main:

```
kol_id|jnj_id|kol_full_nm|foc_area_id|thrc_cd|thrc_nm|dis_area|dis_area_nm|expert_score|pub_scor|rx_scor|refrl_scor|clincl_rsrchr_scor|is_kol
101152|7124166|Constance Ann Benson|1|VIR|VIR|HIV|HIV|45.17|68.5|0|1.69|88|Y
251489|7822721|Mariam S Aziz|1|VIR|VIR|HIV|HIV|44.33|39.5|33|34.26|76|Y
100856|7356682|William Rodney Short|1|VIR|VIR|HIV|HIV|49.49|44|57.5|50.39|48|Y
251460|7933108|Laura A Guay|1|VIR|VIR|HIV|HIV|34.8|63|0|0|48|N
```

df2:

```
filter   filter_value    columns       user_id  password    api_name
kol_id    101152          kol_id        vmani4  abede1234      KOL
thrc_nm    VIR            jnj_id        vmani4  abede1234      KOL
jnj_id    7124166         kol_full_nm   vmani4  abede1234      KOL
                          thrc_cd       vmani4  abede1234      KOL
```

I have to filter out values from df_main using the help of df2.
In df2, it has 3 columns - filter, filter_value and columns. So I have to create match statement like this way -

```
if(kol_id == '101152' and thrc_nm == 'VIR' and jnj_id == '7124166')
   Then extract only those column records from df_main which is present in df2['columns']
```

But the problem is filter and filter_value column records is not certain, means it is changing by the api_name. So i need to write code which is applicable for all the api's.
If you need more info please let me know.

Means final result

```
df_result:

kol_id|jnj_id|kol_full_nm|thrc_cd|
101152|7124166|Constance Ann Benson|VIR
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I took two columns - filter and filter_value from the data frame. created a temporary data frame. Then I transposed the temporary data frame and reset the index and remove the headers.

```
filter_u = df['filter'].unique()
filter_u = [str(i) for i in filter_u]
filter_u = ' '.join(filter_u).split()
column_u = df['columns'].unique()
column_u = [str(i) for i in column_u]
column_u = ' '.join(column_u).split()
print(filter_u)
print(column_u)
df_t1 = df[['filter', 'filter_value']]
df_t1 = df_t1.transpose().reset_index(drop=True)
df_t1 = df_t1.astype(str)
df_t1.columns = df_t1.iloc[0]
df_t1 = df_t1.reindex(df_t1.index.drop(0)).reset_index(drop=True)
df_t1.columns.name = None
```

output of above code:

```
   kol_id thrc_nm     jnj_id
0  101152     VIR  7124166.0
```

Then I read the main file as a data frame and merge with the above data frame and finally I got the result whatever I want.

```
df_main = pd.read_csv("/medaff/Scripts/python/vinooth/kol_scores.txt", delimiter = '|')
df_main = df_main.astype(str)
print(df_main.head())

df_3=pd.merge(df_main,df_t1,on=filter_u,how='inner')
df_3 = df_3[df_3.columns & column_u]
print(df_3)
df_3.to_json('/medaff/Scripts/python/vinooth/output/out.json', orient='records')
```

In this way I got my final Output:

```
   kol_id     jnj_id           kol_full_nm thrc_cd
0  101152  7124166.0  Constance Ann Benson     VIR
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will work -

```
## For this case you'll have to add these 2 lines to avoid comparing str to int
## and to avoid nans in last row of df2
df_final = df_main.copy().astype(str)
df2 = df2[:3].astype(str)

for i, row in df2.iterrows():
    df_final = df_final[df_final[row['filter']]==row['filter_value']]
```

Comment: Error - 'tuple' object has no attribute 'filter'

Comment: Oh yeah sorry iterrows returns tuple i, row, I'll edit

Comment: Also filter is special word so I'll put it in str just in case

Comment: I am getting blank in df_final

Comment: Also blank with row['filter'] instead of row.filter ?

Comment: No result. Blank dataframe

Comment: I believe the problem is that the data, eg the kol_id is sometimes in int, and sometime in str, so its not equal:
str('101152')==int(101152) >>> False

Comment: /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py:1649: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison

Comment: Empty DataFrame
Columns: [kol_id, jnj_id, kol_full_nm, foc_area_id, thrc_cd, thrc_nm, dis_area, dis_area_nm, expert_score, pub_scor, rx_scor, refrl_scor, clincl_rsrchr_scor, is_kol]
Index: []

Comment: Well for me its working so you have an issue with your dataframes